# Wildfly Topology Consul - multiple deregister on shutdown

Tags: consul, wildfly-swarm

I built a webservice using swarm with consul topology. The service is available for several "channels", so at startup I advertise the service for each channel to the topology like this:

```
protected void startup(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object ignore) {
    for (Channel channel : activeChannels) {
        // do some init stuff

        Topology.lookup().advertise(buildUniqueName(channel.name()));
    }
}
```

This is working great and I can see each service with the right name, id and checks in my consul network.

But now when I stop the server it tries to automatically deregister every service several times (up to 5). You can see that scrolling in the logfile, afterwards the server just hangs and exceptions begin to scroll:

```
INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser] (MSC service thread 1-2) Deregister service service-name:<ip-and-port>
INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser] (MSC service thread 1-6) Deregister service service-name:<ip-and-port>
INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser] (MSC service thread 1-4) Deregister service service-name:<ip-and-port>
INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser] (MSC service thread 1-5) Deregister service service-name:<ip-and-port>
INFO  [org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser] (MSC service thread 1-1) Deregister service service-name:<ip-and-port>


ERROR [org.wildfly.swarm.topology] (Thread-26) WFSTOPO0002: Client not registered: [Registration: service-name; <ip-and-port>; [[http]]].: com.orbitz.consul.NotRegisteredException
        at com.orbitz.consul.AgentClient.check(AgentClient.java:404)
        at com.orbitz.consul.AgentClient.checkTtl(AgentClient.java:420)
        at com.orbitz.consul.AgentClient.pass(AgentClient.java:427)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser.lambda$run$2(Advertiser.java:115)
        at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3527)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at org.wildfly.swarm.topology.consul.runtime.Advertiser.run(Advertiser.java:113)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

which is understandable. The problem however is that the server does not complete the shutdown process afterwards. It just hangs.

Is this a bug in wildfly-swarm or do I have to use topology advertise differently?

Wildfly swarm version 2017.5.0
Used fractions topology-consul, jaxrs, cdi, jpa, logging, swagger
war packaging, no main class

Comment: What you probably need to do is the reverse of Topology.lookup().advertise() during shutdown so that there aren't multiples being removed

Comment: From my understanding the consul Advertiser is keeping track of the services by itself and removes them on shutdown. The services are removed clean from consul on shutdown ... the problem is that they are removed multiple times not just once per service ..

Comment: Right, which is why I was suggesting that you intercept the process of "shutdown" so that you can tell Topology to only shutdown each service once.

Comment: How can I "intercept" the shutdown process - meaning that I can prevent others from doing there shutdown stuff? The only ways I know to do cleanup at shutdown is via CDI listen event (@Destroyed) or via Runtime addShutdownHook - both will not prevent Topology from deregistering.

Comment: I was initially thinking you could observe CDI shutdown like you did with startup, but I see that it may likely happen after Consul disconnection.

It's always possible there's a bug in https://github.com/wildfly-swarm/wildfly-swarm/blob/master/fractions/topology-consul/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/topology/consul/runtime/Advertiser.java#L115

I don't know anything about Consul, so not sure what pass() does.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a bug in the code. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SWARM-1427

Will be fixed in 2017.9.0